# React-Native-Navigation: undefined used but not yet registered

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, velo, react-native-navigation

I'm attempting to create a simple app using react-native and [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation). I've downloaded and used the example within the repo in attempt to see where the problem is, and looked at the usage guide, but everything appears to be ok..

However when the app starts the following error is produced:

Navigation.getRegisteredScreen: undefined used but not yet registered.

I've looked at the screen registration, but there are no differences in its implementation than that within the example or usage guide..

**Version Info:**

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.43.0",
"react-native-elements": "^0.10.3",
"react-native-navigation": "^1.0.30",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0"
```

Currently I'm building against Android rather than iOS, code as below. Any pointers most welcome:

**index.android.js**

```
import App from './src/app';
```

**app.js**

```
import {
    Platform
} from 'react-native';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';

//Screen related book keeping
import {registerScreens} from './screens';
registerScreens();

//Create and store tab reference for use within Navigation constructor
const createTabs = () => {
    let tabs = [
        {
            label: 'One',
            screens: 'TestApp.HomeScreen',
            icon: require('../img/one.png'),
            selectedIcon: require('../img/one_selected.png'),
            title: 'Home'
        },
        {
            label: 'Two',
            screens: 'TestApp.CodeScreen',
            icon: require('../img/two.png'),
            selectedIcon: require('../img/two_selected.png'),
            title: 'Codes'
        },
    ];
    return tabs;
};
//this will start the app
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
    tabs: createTabs(),
    tabsStyle: {
        tabBarBackgroundColor: '#0f2362',
        tabBarButtonColor: '#ffffff',
        tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#63d7cc'
    },
    appStyle: {
        orientation: 'portrait'
    },
});
```

**/src/screens/index.android.js**

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import CodeScreen from './CodeScreen';

// register all screens of the app (including internal ones)
export function registerScreens () {
  Navigation.registerComponent('TestApp.HomeScreen', () => HomeScreen);
  Navigation.registerComponent('TestApp.CodeScreen', () => CodeScreen);
}
```

**/src/screens/CodeScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { Navigation, Screen } from 'react-native-navigation';

export default class CodeScreen extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Change Buttons</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Change Title</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Switch To Tab#1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Set Tab Badge</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Toggle Tabs</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  button: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop:10,
    color: 'blue'
  }
});
```

**/src/screens/HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  Platform
} from 'react-native';
import { Navigation, Screen } from 'react-native-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // if you want to listen on navigator events, set this up
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Push Plain Screen</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Push Styled Screen</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Show Modal Screen</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.button}>Show LightBox</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> : false
        }

        {
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.button}>Show In-App Notification</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> : false
        }

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Show Single Screen App</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    color: 'blue'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a wrong key to specify the `screen`. In your code:

```js
const createTabs = () => {
  let tabs = [{
      label: 'One',
      screens: 'TestApp.HomeScreen',
      icon: require('../img/one.png'),
      selectedIcon: require('../img/one_selected.png'),
      title: 'Home'
    },
    {
      label: 'Two',
      screens: 'TestApp.CodeScreen',
      icon: require('../img/two.png'),
      selectedIcon: require('../img/two_selected.png'),
      title: 'Codes'
    },
  ];
  return tabs;
};
```

Instead of using `screens`, replace it with `screen`.